# My website's apsx pages are redireting to non apsx pages automatically

Tags: redirect

My website's apsx pages are redireting to non apsx pages automatically on both server & local host.
How can I resolve this using web config?

Tried different codes in web config file but it did not work.
I want my web pages to be opened with .aspx extension.